# Positive Definitness of Noise Covariance Matrix in Kalman Filter

Tags: matrix, kalman-filter

I am reading a paper on [Kalman filter](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/292145072_Information_Filter_and_Kalman_Filter_Comparison_Selection_of_the_Faster_Filter) and trying to understand measurement noise covariance and positive definitness of the covariance matrix. It is mentioned in the paper that if the matrix is positive definite then then no measurement is exact. I fail to see how is this the case

> The existence of the inverse matrices that appear in Kalman filter  equations  is  guaranteed  in  the  case  where  the measurements  noise  covariances \$R_k\$ are  positive  definite, denoted  by \$R_k > 0\$;  this  happens  in  the  case  where  no measurement is exact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a covariance matrix is **positive definite** it has no zero eigenvalue, so it is **invertible**.

If you had an exact measurement, it would not have a covariance with itself(variance) or any other measurements, that will probably make it **positive semi-definite**, with a zero eigenvalue associated with that exact sensor.

For a covariance matrix

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} A_1 &0 &A_2\\ 0 & 0 & 0\\ A_3 & 0 &A_4\end{pmatrix},$$

The eigenvalues will be determined by

$$ det(sI-A) = det\begin{pmatrix} sI-A_1 &0 &-A_2\\ 0 & s & 0\\ -A_3 & 0 &sI-A_4\end{pmatrix},$$

$$ det(sI-A) = (-1)^ks \,det\begin{pmatrix} sI-A_1 &-A_2\\-A_3 &sI-A_4\end{pmatrix},$$

So having an exact measurement would lead you to have a zero eigenvalue associated with that measurement. And the covariance matrix would not be invertible.

Comment: i guess it does make sense because having a variance does indeed mean that the measurement is not exact! I just realized this now. So if having a variance does indeed mean that the measurement is not exact then why add "redundancy" by implicitly mentioning it?

Comment: also shouldnt "non-zero determinant" be the measure of matrix being invertible or not? Also in case if "some measure is exact" instead of "no measure is exact" do we get a "semi" positive definite matrix? I am just trying to understand the distinction between the author's mentioning of "no measurement is exact"

Comment: It is the same thing $$\det(A) = \prod^n_{i=1} \lambda_i$$

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that, in my answer I go through the positive semi-definite part. But notice this happens due to properties of covariance.

Comment: well i think i got it: so having an exact measurement or mixtures of (exact and noisy) measurement will lead to semi-positive definite matrix right?

Comment: very nice explanation indeed. See if you can contribute to [this as well](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3599167/is-positive-semi-definiteness-of-a-matrix-a-loose-measure-of-independence) if convenient.

Comment: Yes, if all of them are noisy -> positive definite. If you have one or more exact measurements -> positive semi-definite.

Comment: There's a subtlety in the "non-zero determinant" bit -- in order for the covariance matrix to be *valid* it needs to be positive definite or semi-definite.  If it has any negative eigenvalues then it is representing a physically impossible situation.